# Stylesheet failed to parse, MIME type Error

Tags: css

I am designing a website, one of the stylesheets I am taking directly from Raw Github user content:

```
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bigfishtv/turret/master/dist/turret.css
```

But when I try and use it, I get this error:

```
Did not parse stylesheet at 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bigfishtv/turret/master
/dist/turret.css'  because non CSS MIME types are not allowed for cross-origin stylesheets.
```

What is the cause of this error?

it parses perfectly if I do this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/turret.css" />
```

But I would rather not have to download the stylesheets.

Comment: Post your code for how you're trying to include this stylesheet please.

Comment: Fixed it, downloaded the stylesheet locally and it parsed with out errors, what the hell?

Comment: GitHub serves files with `Content-Type: text/plain`, i.e. a "non CSS MIME type" as your browser calls it. You could always fetch it via XHR if you really wanted to, but GitHub is not a CDN and files stored there are neither guaranteed to stay at the same URL, not to have any backwards compatibility. If you're looking for a CDN, [cdnjs is hosting a copy of bigfishtv/turret](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bigfishtv-turret).

Comment: @Tom What the browser was doing was security. You won't "what the hell" when you get hacked or phished by a hacker using a browser with no plugins.